# Unsure of the technical term - HTML/CSS/Javascript table questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML/CSS/Javascript related question, but I'm unsure of exactly how to ask, as I've long since forgotten the technical terms for everything.

My ultimate goal is to construct (code) a webpage element that does the following:

-Has a number of clickable elements (graphical buttons, not HTML "buttons") that, when clicked, display a variable amount of text that provides interesting details about certain things. If possible, some way to have these buttons "highlight" would be desired (I know how to pull off a CSS trick where the image is swapped up/down or left/right by coordinates when clicked, but I'm unsure of how to get this to work with what I intend).

-Allows me to affix some kind of a label in front of each button. (My original plan was to throw everything into an HTML table, so I could have a column on one side of the buttons that I can type labels into).

-Allows me to have an image background appear when the detail box pops up.

-Is organized such that the buttons and their title plates are on one side of the detail box, and the detail box itself is on the other side.

Example:

I have a column on the far left that has names of fruits (Apple, Orange, Banana, Pear). In a column immediately next to these names is a series of buttons aligned with each fruit name (one button per fruit name, so "Apple" then {button} on one row, then "Orange" then {button} on the next row, etc.). Clicking on that button will display, on the far right, a detailed description of each fruit, with a background image (same image for all of these detail boxes) behind this detailing text. This background image, and any text, would be hidden until a button is clicked. I would prefer it that if the same button is clicked twice, the text is once again hidden.

I've no problem constructing images for all of this, but I'm lost on the code. Is it possible to code all of this as some sort of HTML Table, so I can keep it organized? Would it be possible to have the far left column (example) have a background image, then replaceable text on top of it (thus decreasing the number of graphics)?

I apologize if my question and phrasing isn't technically descriptive. I've long since gotten too used to simple HTML pages and never really learned CSS/Javascript. If my question doesn't make sense, I'd be more than happy to draw an image to better explain my goal.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: You're describing what sounds like a normal feature on any contemporary webpage. You don't need to lay it out with tables. You can use a combination of any or all of fixed/relative positioning, floats, css columns and flexbox. You can make it interactive with javascript or a javascript library like jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As @rounin says, there is nothing out of the ordinary about what you are describing, in fact it's in the tl;dr category. It sounds like you need to spend some time genning up on what the technology can do for you.  It would be helpful to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as it will help you format questions more succinctly (and save some typing time)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no single "right" way to do what you're asking.  There's dozens of ways to approach this problem.  It comes down to: 1) How much time do you want to spend building the solutions, and 2) Would it be an issue if you added different technologies to your project (such as Bootstrap or jQuery)?

To look it at from a general viewpoint:

There's a rule of thumb I heard somewhere that I think helps in situations like this.  Every single thing on your page is a rectangle.  Everything.  All you're really doing is naming, styling, and manipulating these rectangles.

Any element, id, or class that you create on your html page can be manipulated by your css or javascript.  And if it doesn't exist on your html page, then you can create it with css or javascript and *then* manipulate it.

Anything can be made into a "button", not just items specifically called out as buttons.  You can choose whichever rectangles you want to be your "buttons"; you would just have to target and style them as such.

(As a piece of advice, though, I would recommend sticking with html's `<button>` functionality.  Standardized semantics is good for everyone all around, and you can change the look and feel of these buttons however you want by using css).

To be more specific:

The traditional way to handle the hiding or showing of information on the page is by using javascript and/or jQuery.

Give all common html elements to be manipulated a class name `class="example-class"`, and give any unique elements to be manipulated an id name `id="example-id"`.

[Here's the jQuery page regarding .hide() and .show()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp).  (If you have any specific issues with these methods, then Stack Overflow can help).  You would target the classes or ids that you named in the html.

As for organizing your page, using and nesting `<div>` tags is usually the way to go.  Bootstrap comes with special classes that can help with the necessary roles: `class="row"` to help with the horizontals, `class="col-SIZE-NUM"` to help with the verticals, and `class="well"` to help with organizing sections.

Bootstrap's main page has a pretty good overview on your options: [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

All of the above can be done with vanilla css and vanilla javascript as well.  It's up to you to decide if you want to (or are even able to) make things a little easier for yourself here.

Hope this helps!